# comparing performance of two ubuntu system when running one application?

Tags: performance, benchmarks

I have two computers, both running Ubuntu 22.04
One computer is a laptop, the other a desktop.
On both computer I installed FlightGear (flight simulator), and i am surprised that the application (which should be system-demanding) runs better on the laptop than on the desktop.

Is there a way I can "test" or monitor the performance of both computers when running this application ?!
So I can see why the desktop computer appears to be slow...
My desktop computer is connected to a huge screen , so the bottleneck may be the graphic card I have on the desktop...

Any hint appreciated !
Vincent